# Search in string for multiple array values

Tags: bash, if-statement, for-loop

I'm looking at a simple for loop with the following logic:

```
variable=`some piped string`
array_value=(1.1 2.9)

for i in ${array_value[@]}; do
if [[ "$variable" == *some_text*"$array_value" ]]; then
    echo -e "Info: Found a matching string"
fi
```

The problem is that I cannot get this to show me when it finds either the string ending in 1.1 or 2.9 as sample data.

If I do an `echo $array_value` in the for loop I can see that the array values are being taken so its values are being parsed, though the if loop doesn't return that echo message although the string is present.

---

LE: 
Based on the comments received I've abstracted the code to something like this, which still doesn't work if I want to use wildcards inside the comparison quote

```
versions=(1.1 2.9)
string="system is running version:2.9"

for i in ${versions[@]}; do
        if [[ "$string" == "system*${i}" ]]; then
                echo "match found"
        fi
done
```

Any construction similar to "system* ${i}" or "* ${i}" will not work, though if I specify the full string pattern it will work.

Comment: `echo $array_value` will give first element of array. You need to access `$i`.

Comment: `"$array_value"` is the same as `"${array_value[0]}" so is always `1.1`. Did you mean `"$i"` there? What does the input data (`$variable`) look like?

Comment: post sample string which hold by `variable`. Also here `*some_text*"$array_value"`. So post sample string for what is `some_text` and i think you mean `*some_text*"$i"`.

Comment: Yes, I meant to say $i which will give 1.1 and 2.9 in the for loop.

Other than that, the sample variable string will look something like "version detected found is: 1.1" but it can be one of the 2 array values so that's why I need to check for both, which can extend in the future so I need the array to be expandable.

Comment: Why do't you use grep for this purpose? `echo "$variable" | grep -o -w 'some_text\(1\.1\|2\.9\)'`

Comment: @user3144292 in `for..loop`. you need something like `if echo "$variable" | grep "$i" >/dev/null;then echo -e "Info: Found a matching string"; fi`.

Comment: See [BashGuide on arrays](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Arrays) for helpful information on how to use arrays in bash

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the test construct has to you with your `if` statement. To construct the `if` statement in a form that will evaluate, use:

```
if [[ "$variable" == "*some_text*${i}" ]]; then
```

**Note:** `*some_text*` will need to be replaced with actual text without `*` wildcards. If the `*` is needed in the text, then you will need to turn globbing off to prevent expansion by the shell. If expansion is your goal, then protect the variable `i` by braces.

There is nothing wrong with putting `*some_text*` up against the variable `i`, but it is cleaner, depending on the length of some_text, to assign it to a variable itself. The easiest way to accommodate this would be to define a variable to hold the `some_text` you are needing. E.g.:

```
prefix="some_text"
if [[ "$variable" == "${prefix}${i}" ]]; then
```

If you have additional questions, just ask.

Comment: The test doesn't need quotes and works just fine with globbing.  The point of using wildcards in tests is to match against unknown text.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I've updated the initial thread, can you please check on it.
JohnB I need to use wildcards due to the construction of the parsed string, on which I only want to do a basic pattern matching with the use of wildcards, then get to the version matching loop.

Comment: The working version I could come up so far is not to use quotes "" and use [[:blank:]] for the spaces between the searched string.

Answer (score -1):

Change `"system*${i}"` to `system*$i`.

Wrapping with quotes inside `[[ ... ]]` nullifies the wildcard `*` by treating it as a literal character.

Or if you want the match to be assigned to a variable:

```
match="system*"
```

you can then do:

```
[[ $string == $match$i ]]
```

You actually don't need quotes around `$string` either as word splitting is not performed inside `[[ ... ]]`.

From man bash:

```
[[ expression ]]
    ...
    Word splitting and pathname expansion are not 
    performed on the words between the [[ and ]]
    ...
    Any part of the pattern may be quoted to force 
    the quoted portion to be matched as a string.
```